# Objective-C property - getter behaviour

Tags: objective-c, properties, getter

What is technically wrong with the following:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger timestamp;
@property(nonatomic, readonly, getter = timestamp) NSUInteger startTime;
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger endTime;
```

I am sure I can find a better way to organise this, but this is what I ended up with at one point in my project and I noticed that **accessing the startTime property always returned 0, even when the timestamp property was set to a correct timestamp**.

It seems having set the getter of startTime to an existing property (timestamp), it is not forwarding the value of timestamp when I do:

```
event.startTime => 0
event.timestamp => 1340920893
```

All these are timestamps by the way.

Just a reminder, I know the above should have happened in my project but I don't understand why accessing startTime doesn't forward onto timestamp property.

UPDATE

In my implementation I am synthesising all of these properties:

```
@synthesize timestamp, endTime, startTime;
```

Please check an example object to use that demonstrates this at my gist on GitHub: https://gist.github.com/3013951

Comment: What's the error? With `getter`?

Comment: Actually, my answer was wrong. It doesn't matter if you have multiple properties linked to the same selector. I'd say there is no problem with this...

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I only ran my test in the latest XCode in an ARC project. It may be possible this was a change in Clang at some point.

Comment: I am not getting an error when I access startTime but the value is always 0 no matter what timestamp property is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your description method, you aren't using the property, you're accessing the ivar.

```
-(NSString*) description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Event< timestamp:%d, start:%d >", 
             timestamp, 
             startTime]; // <-- This is accessing the instance variable, not the property.
}
```

This will work for you:

```
-(NSString*) description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Event< timestamp:%d, start:%d >", 
             timestamp, 
             self.startTime]; // <-- This is using the property accessor.
}
```

The property-vs-ivar thing messes people up all the time, so excuse me while I ramble on about it for a minute.  :)  If you already know all of this, skip ahead.

When you create and synthesize a property, as you did above, two things happen:

1. an ivar is created of the proper type.
2. a getter function is created, which returns that ivar.

The important part about point 2 is that, by default, *the ivar and the getter function (and therefore, the property) have the same names*.

So this:

```
@interface Event
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger timestamp;
@property(nonatomic, readonly, getter = timestamp) NSUInteger startTime;
@end

@implementation Event
@synthesize timestamp, startTime;
@end
```

...turns into this:

```
@interface Event {
    NSUInteger timestamp;
    NSUInteger startTime;
}
@end

@implementation Event
- (NSUInteger) timestamp {
    return timestamp
}

- (void) setTimestamp:(NSUInteger) ts {
    timestamp = ts;
}

- (NSUInteger) startTime {
    return [self timestamp];
}
@end
```

How dot syntax works is that this:

```
NSUInteger foo = myEvent.startTime;
```

really does

```
NSUInteger foo = [myEvent startTime];
```

All of that to say that when you access an ivar, you're... well, accessing an ivar.  When you use a property, you're calling a function which returns a value.  More importantly, it's exceedingly easy to do one thing when you meant the other, because the syntax is so very similar.  It's for this reason that many people routinely synthesize their ivars with leading underscores, so that it's harder to mess up.

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger timestamp;
@property(nonatomic, readonly, getter = timestamp) NSUInteger startTime;

@synthesize timestamp = _timestamp;
@synthesize startTime = _startTime;

NSLog( @"startTime = %d", _startTime );  // OK, accessing the ivar.
NSLog( @"startTime = %d", self.startTime );  // OK, using the property.
NSLog( @"startTime = %d", startTime );  // NO, that'll cause a compile error, and 
                                        // you'll say "whoops", and then change it 
                                        // to one of the above, thereby avoiding
                                        // potentially hours of head-scratching.  :)
```

Comment: Of course. spot on. It was so simple it was complicated ! Sometimes you are looking past the surface and too deep into something. Again a silly question by myself... Thank you for the answer. Interesting to note that I usually use the underscore implementation but for some reason this class of mine was very simple and I decided to keep it with even less code. Lesson of the day: Keep your coding style. Oh and don't ask questions on Stack Overflow without going truly insane first

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you synthesize in the correct order so the getter exists for `startTime`.

```
//implementation
@synthesize timestamp;
@synthesize statTime;
```

Comment: I didn't pay particular attention to the ordering of this but it turns out I am doing that. Unless I need to specifically set the synthesise on a new line. I am doing @synthesize p1, p2, p3; Maybe this isn't doesn't prioritise the properties ?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I am using Apple LLVM 3.1 and it is working fine for me.

Comment: I'm using the same. I just posted a link to a sample code, please test it on your side if you would be so kind.